# List Time Zones in Windows 8 / WinRT / XAML apps?

Tags: c#, timezone, windows-8, winrt-xaml

It used to be that we would use `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` to enumerate time zones.

How do you do it in Windows 8 apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just 
[blogged](http://novotny.org/blog/converting-timezones-in-store-winrt-apps) about how to do this and included the code you need as a 
[gist](https://gist.github.com/3896181).

Also, to address another commenter, no, ARM compatibility is not an issue as the marshaling happens correctly.

EDIT: just made it one better and turned it into a general purpose NuGet package:

https://nuget.org/packages/WinRTTimeZones

The source is here: https://github.com/onovotny/WinRTTimeZones

Comment: I tried your library but it seems to be missing some timezones. Where's the timezone for sao paolo? Also, I wish the short timezone IDs could be used ie. EST.

Comment: Hi Cal, the list of Time Zones comes from the Windows Registry. Unfortunately, there's no standard for either time zone names or abbreviations, so you'll need to create your own.

You can see the list Windows uses and the mappings to TZID's here:
http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/zone_tzid.html

Answer (score 1):

Per [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/b3021654-0a34-409c-8afa-54ebd7df8ff4) you'll have to roll your own approach, perhaps through a service that exposes the [ICANN data](http://www.iana.org/time-zones)?

Via PInvoke ([EnumDynamicTimeZoneInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706893%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) you could get a subset of them.  And even with [GetSystemTimeZones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397781.aspx) you wouldn't be guaranteed to get them all either (though I expect more than with the PInvoke).

Comment: PInvoke in WinRT kills ARM compatibility, too